# Extjs 5 login form - How working?

Tags: javascript, forms, codeigniter, extjs, authentication

I have a very simple Extjs 5 login form: 
Ext.onReady(function () {

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();

Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';

var login_form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    url: 'verifylogin/index',
    monitorValid: true,
    labelWidth: 75,
    frame: true,
    height: 170,          
    width: 360, 
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: { 
        allowBlank: false 
    },
    items: [
        { 
            fieldLabel: 'Username', 
            name: 'username',
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'capslockdetector',
                title: 'Caps lock is on',
                message: 'Caps Lock is ON!'
            }] 
        },{ 
            fieldLabel: 'Password', 
            name: 'password', 
            inputType: 'password',
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'capslockdetector',
                title: 'Caps lock is on',
                message: 'Caps Lock is ON!'
            }]
        }],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,
            handler: function (btn, evt) { 
                login_form.getForm().submit();
            }
        }]
});

var login_window = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'window',
    title: 'Login',
    modal: true,
    height: 200,
    width: 370,
    items: [login_form]
});

login_window.show();
```

});

This form send username and password my codeigniter controller. This controller check data: If user give bad username and password then $this->load->view('login_view'); (This is the extjs login form and window).
If user give good data then $this->load->view('good_view'); .

My code: (verifylogin/index)

```
if($login == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('login_view');
   }
else {
     $this->load->view('good_view');
}
```

My problem: The form and controller is working, but I can't see view('login_view') or view('good_view'). I wrote close() event (then user give good data) but I can't see $this->load->view('good_view');.
Only I can't see more of the login window.

Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: Write out your code. Code in a paragraph is not very understandable.

Comment: If i understand, you want to redirect user to "good_view" if he sent good login/pwd ?

Comment: Benoit Cuvelier: Yes.